# Element.prototype.matches not matching naked :pseudoclass

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, pseudo-class

For some reason, Element.prototype.matches returns false for a perfectly valid CSS selector (`:hover`):

```
let n = /* an HTMLAnchorElement whose state is forced to :hover */;
console.log(n.matches(':hover')); // false
console.log(n.matches('a:hover')); // true
console.log(n.matches('*:hover')); // false
```

- I ran that code in the dev tools console, after finding a DOM node, forcing its state to :hover using the Elements panel, and then setting `n` to `$0`.
- `n` could be any HTML dom node in the page - it's not restricted to anchor elements.

Further, using `document.querySelector` exhibits the same behavior - but only on my local testing environment. For example, https://google.com/ returns true for all those tests.

Comment: Please add the relevant markup/setup for a [mcve]

Comment: Presumably the minimal reproducible example is to paste something like `document.querySelector('.js-add-link').addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target }) => console.log(target.matches(':hover')))` into the console and then hover over the add comment link? I did that, and I get true for all the examples you provide

Comment: @OliverRadini The issue has less to do with a mouseover handler and more to do with the :hover selector. I was merely testing it in the mouseover handler.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my page. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode for more information.